# Adobe Reader embedded in WinForms app hangs on close

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, adobe-reader

(This appears to be caused by a recent update to Adobe Reader.)

We have a WinForms app that embeds an Adobe Reader through a `WebBrowser` control (i.e., *not* by referencing the ActiveX DLL directly). When closing the last instance of that control, the entire app hangs for about 15 seconds.

I can "work around" this by not disposing the control; see also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41022136/1600). But that hardly sounds like a safe solution.

During the hang,

- nothing of note happens in our user-level code, according to dotTrace
- nothing at all happens in the `AcroRd32` process, according to ProcMon. Literally zilch. There's lots of activity before the hang for a second or two, then nothing, then it starts again another almost exactly 15 seconds later.

I'm guessing this is some kind of lock with a timeout, but I don't really know how to track this down any further.